# How to get an assignment from a method?

Tags: java, javaparser

I want to collect methods in a class that set a certain field e.g. `int i = 2;`.
I know how to get the `Statement`s of a method:

```
CompilationUnit cu = StaticJavaParser.parse("class A {private int i; public int SetI(int i){this.i=i;}}");
List<MethodDeclaration> methods = cu.findAll(MethodDeclaration.class);
Statement statements = md.getBody().get().getStatements().get(0);
if (statement.isReturnStmt())
    var r = statement.asReturnStmt();
```

but [assignments](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.github.javaparser/javaparser-core/3.19.0/index.html) seem to be expressions and I have no Idea how to get to them. How can I get the (assignment) expressions in a method?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (statemet.isExpressionStmt()) {
    Expression e = statement.asExpressionStmt().getExpression();
```

does the trick.